# JFrame data is gone when the frame is minimized

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jtextfield

I am developing an Java JFrame application in this I had

1. `JTextField`
2. `JTable`

In that **the data of text field stored in database and display it via table.**

It display the data successfully from database. But the issue is **when I minimize the frame the table data is gone every time.**  Is there any option to display data even user minimize the frame?

Or, is there any Other option to solve the issue?

### Code:

```
public void insertTaskDetail(){
    global.dbConnect();
    String insertkeydetail = "{call sp_inserttaskdetail(?,?,?,?)}";
    try{
        CallableStatement callableStatement;
        callableStatement = global.con.prepareCall(insertkeydetail);
        System.out.println("Stored Procedure Insert Key Detail is Called");
        String dt=global.getCurrentDateTime();
        System.out.println(dt);
        callableStatement.setString("p1", jText_Task_Name.getText().toString());
        callableStatement.setString("p2", dt);
        callableStatement.setString("p3", "0");
        callableStatement.setString("p4", L_Id);
        callableStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Task Detail is successfully inserted in database");
        global.con.commit();
        showtask();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Sql Exception Add Task Changed:"+e.toString());
    }
}

public void showtask(){
    global.dbConnect();
    String showtask = "{call sp_showtask(?,?)}";
    try{
        callableStatement = global.con.prepareCall(showtask, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        System.out.println("Stored Procedure Get Task Detail is Called");
        callableStatement.setString("p1", L_Id);
        callableStatement.setString("p2", "false");
        rs=callableStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs.toString());
        //Task , Start Time , Finish Time , Completed
        String task, st;
        boolean cmp;
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            i++;
        }

        data=new Object[i][];
        int j=0;
        rs.first();
        if(i>0){
            do{
                System.out.println(i);
                task=rs.getString("Task");
                System.out.println(task);
                st=rs.getString("Start Time");
                cmp=rs.getBoolean("Completed");
                data[j] = new Object[]{task, st, cmp};
                j++;
            }while(rs.next());
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Sql Exception:"+e.toString());
    }
    jText_Task_Name.setText("");
    TableDataModel();
}

public void TableDataModel(){
    String[] cols = {"<html>Task<br>Name</html>", "<html>Start<br>Time</html>", "Finished"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols){
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col){
            return col == 2 ? Boolean.class : String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
            return column==2 ? true : false;
        }
    };

    table = new JTable(model){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return column==2 ? true : false;
        }
    };

    table.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14));
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14));
    table.getTableHeader().enable(false);

    JCheckBox jcheckBox=new JCheckBox();
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    System.out.println("Column Model:"+columnModel.toString());
    columnModel.getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jcheckBox));

    jcheckBox.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
            int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
            for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
                Boolean selected = (Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 2);
                if(selected != null && selected){
                    System.out.println("Removed:"+i);
                    model.removeRow(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    JScrollPane jScrollpane=new JScrollPane(table);
    jScrollpane.setViewportView(table);
    this.add(jScrollpane);
    jScrollpane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14));
    jScrollpane.setBounds(10, 130, 295, 190);

    call++;
}
```

Comment: Without a runnable example to demonstrate your problem, there's nothing anybody can possibly do...

Comment: Ok wait I post the code

Comment: Note: Uncompilable code snippet != runnable example.  For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal **Complete** Tested and Readable Example).  Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: `jScrollpane.setBounds(10, 130, 295, 190);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: But I got Complete output means my program is running succesfully just the problem is data is not stable means when i minimise the window of jframe the data is gone from jtable.

Comment: `public void TableDataModel()`  Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I would conclude you are using a `null` layout manager, which would be the reason you're having issues.

Make use of appropriate [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and let it take care of it for you